# Extract Word from string using Regular Expression in Notepad ++

Tags: regex, string

I have one string, which is `('Hassiotis, Sophia(SH1)')`,

I want only SH1 from that.

What should be the regular expression?

Thank You.

I am using Notepad ++

Comment: Ask a leading question, and you get the answers you are looking for... :o)
**1)** This regular expression will match SH1 : "SH1"
**2)** If you are looking for an arbitrary expression that matches a certain string you will have to describe what you are looking for! What comes before SH1? After? Is it always SH1 that you are looking for? Is SH1 always written with capital letters? Is "('Hassiotis, Sophia(SH1)')" the string always?

Answer (score 0):

As from yor question `SH1` would suffice ;-), but I suspect your wan't to have somthing more flexible.

```
\('.*\((.*)\)'\)
```

might be a solution. It requires a newer Notepad++, I guess. The matched string may be referenced with `\1` in the replacement string.